# Ist ein Buchstabe eine Nummer?

Tags: meaning

Angenommen, man hat diese Liste:

> a. etwas 
>   b. etwas anderes 
>   c. noch etwas anderes

Ich habe "Nummer a" und "Nummer b" in diesem Kontext gehört. Sind Buchstaben Nummern? Gibt es andere Zeichen, die Nummern sind?

Comment: Aus der Schule kenne ich "Wer hat die Nummer b?" Als Abkürzung für "1b", "2b" oder was auch immer, je nach Kontext, aber diese Verwendung ist glaube ich sehr spezifisch auf das Klassenzimmer beschränkt. Häufiger war auch "Wer hat die b?", ganz ohne Nummer.

Comment: Insbesondere höre und sage ich Sachen wie `Aufgabe Nummer b`, `Punkt Nummer a`, `Argument Nummer c`, oder auch umgs. `Aufgabe Nummero d`.

Answer (score 26):

Kommt mir irgendwie seltsam vor, das so zu sagen... Habe ich jedenfalls noch nie in der Form gehört. Ich würde eher "Punkt A", "Punkt B" etc. sagen.

Eine numerische Liste wiederum würde man denke ich auch eher mit "Erstens", "Zweitens" oder eben auch "Punkt Eins", "Punkt Zwei" bezeichnen und weniger mit "Nummer Eins", "Nummer Zwei"...

Zeichen die Nummern sind kenne ich nur noch die Römischen Ziffern I, V, X, L, C, D und M - wer diese lesen kann wird sie meistens auch als Zahl aussprechen und nicht als Buchstabenfolge.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Ich habe allerdings auch schon "Nummer A" gehört :)

Comment: Klingt für mich irgendwie nach Beamtensprech oder so...

Comment: Kenne ich nur von Kandidaten bei "Wer Wird Millionär", die "Nummer 1" meinen, "A" lesen und dann "Nummer A" sagen :)

Comment: MMXI ist allerdings eine römische Zahl, und eine Nummer, aber keine Ziffer. Zwar sind alleinestehende, römische Ziffern auch Nummern, aber es geht ja nicht nur um Ziffern und Zeichen, sondern um Zahlen und Nummern. Ich würde ja, als alter Tautologe, sagen: Nummern sind Zeichenkombinationen, die etwas nummerieren.

Comment: Ich denke es kommt auf den Kontext an. Wenn ich "Punkt A" höre, denke z.B. ich an einen TOP einer Tagesordnung, also Etwas, wo mehrere Dinge aufeinander folgen. Wenn ich allerdings eine Auswahl habe, von denen ich eine auswählen kann, würde ich eher zu `Möglichkeit` oder `Option` tendieren - "Punkt A" erscheint mir dann merkwürdig.

Comment: +1 für "Punkt". "Punkt A", "Punkt Eins", "Punkt Römisch-Eins", etc.

Comment: @Florian: öffentliche Verwaltung war auch mein erster Gedanke...

Answer (score 19):

> Sind Buchstaben Nummern?

**Ja**.
Mathematisch gesehen ist die Formulierung komplett unproblematisch: Die Ziffern 0 bis 9 sind nur *eine* mögliche Konvention für ein (dezimales) Zahlensystem. Bei anderen Systemen (z. B. mit größerer Basis) wird dieses Symbolalphabet entsprechend erweitert (z. B. für die hexadezimalen Zahlen, wo man noch „a“ bis „f“ hinzunimmt).

In diesem Zusammenhang spricht man ganz natürlich von Ziffern, und zusammengesetzte Ziffern ergeben dann Nummern. „af“ ist also eine ganz normale hexadezimale Nummer.

Das ist natürlich allgemeingültig, d. h., auch in einem nicht-hexadezimalen System kann „a“ eine Nummer sein, und wenn man eine Nummerierung „a, b, c, …“ vornimmt, dann ist das ein typisches Beispiel davon.

Zusammengefasst: Es ist im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch vielleicht nicht üblich, aber es ist strenggenommen korrekt und teilweise (insbesondere im technisch-naturwissenschaftlichen Sprachgebrauch) eben sehr wohl üblich, hier von Nummern zu sprechen.

> Gibt es andere Zeichen, die Nummern sind?

Ja. Man kann Ziffern beliebig definieren. Eine andere *typische* Nummerierung findet sich in Fußnoten-Symbolen: „*, †, ‡, §, ‖, ¶“. Außerdem gibt es natürlich noch römische Nummerierung, „I, II, III, IV, V, …“ (und in Kleinschreibung „i, ii, iii, iv, v, …“).

Außerdem gibt es diverse benannte Konstanten, die bestimmte Nummern beschreiben, wie z. B. die Kreiszahl π.

Comment: Es dürfte allerdings auch im technisch-naturwissenschaftlichen Bereich eher unüblich sein, eine Aufzählung mit zehn zu beginnen ;)

Comment: Sehe ich anders: Buchstaben sind keine Nummern, sondern Buchstaben werden - z. B. von Mathematikern, oder in Aufzählungen - als *Namen* für *Zahlen* verwendet. Buchstaben sind natürlich Buchstaben. Dass die naive Char-Implementierung der meisten Programmiersprachen intern Buchstaben auf Zahlen mappt, sollte uns hier nicht interessieren.

Comment: @fzwo „Nummer“ = „Name für eine Zahl“. Eine Nummer (bzw. Ziffer) ist schlicht ein Aufzählungszeichen aus einem willkürlich gewählten Symbolalphabet. [Siehe Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ziffer#Bedeutung1).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Du verlinkst auf "Ziffer". Auf [Nummer](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Nummer) steht ausdrücklich, dass es eine *Zahl* (kein Buchstabe oder sonstiges Zeichen) ist. Eine Nummer ist also in diesem Fall wohl der spezialfall einer *numerischen* Ziffer.

Comment: @fzwo Die Definitionen sind ganz klar, und Du verwendest sie falsch: Ziffer = atomarer Bestandteil aus einem Symbolalphabet. Zahl (Nummer) = Zusammensetzung (Sequenz) von Ziffern. Jede Ziffer ist gleichzeitig auch eine (aus einer Ziffer bestehende) Zahl. Siehe auch [Wikipedia: Nummer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nummer) (insbesondere das Beispielbild!) und [Wikipedia: Ziffer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziffer), zweiter Absatz.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Wikipedia sieht mir das zu mathematisch, ich sehe es eher sprachlich. Auch der Duden schreibt, eine Nummer sei eine *Zahl, die etwas kennzeichnet*. Sprachlich ist es zumindest unschön, eine "Nummer b" zu haben, vielleicht sogar falsch (es sei denn, man befindet sich auf bestimmten Fachgebieten wie Mathematik und nutzt die speziellen, von der Alltagssprache abweichenden Bedeutungen von deren Fachsprache). Es mag natürlich sein, dass der Duden das "zu polpulärwissenschaftlich" sieht - der Mensch von der Straße wird das sicherlich auch tun.

Comment: @fzwo Der Duden widerspricht dem aber auch nirgendwo. Die mathematische Definition ist lediglich rigoroser, nicht aber allgemeiner. Insbesondere wird hier nichts *umdefiniert*, nur *formalisiert*.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Der Duden sagt, es sei eine *Zahl*. Der Duden gibt zu den meisten Wörtern nicht an, was sie alles nicht sind. Die mathematische Definition ist in der Tat allgemeiner (denn sie schließt nicht-Zahlen ein). Wie auch immer, in der Alltagssprache wird kaum jemand jemals zu einem Buchstaben "Nummer" sagen.

Comment: @fzwo Und sagt der Duden auch, was eine Zahl ist? Ja, tut er: „durch ein bestimmtes Zeichen oder eine Kombination von Zeichen darstellbarer abstrakter Begriff, mit dessen Hilfe gerechnet, mathematische Operationen durchgeführt werden können“ … Sorry, der Duden ist einfach mal eindeutig auf meiner Seite.

Comment: `Buchstaben sind keine Nummern` würde ich auch nicht sagen, aber `Buchstaben können Nummern sein`. Ersteres behauptet ja, dass alle Buchstaben Nummern sind, aber meistens sind sie es nicht. Auch passt ja der Buchstabe als isoliertes Zeichen eher auf `Ziffer`. In obigem Beispiel wäre `... x), y), z), aa), ab), ac)` also `ab` eine Nummer, aber nicht mehr ein Buchstabe. Schlußfolgerung: In speziellen Fällen nur ist ein Buchstabe eine Nummer. Keinesfalls kann man generell Buchstabe durch Nummer substituieren.

Comment: @user: Ja, da hast Du recht. Buchstaben können Ziffern sein. Ich habe vereinfacht, da jede Ziffer ja auch gleichzeitig eine Nummer ist.

Comment: Nach Deiner Definition einer Nummer (nämlich einer endlichen Kette von Ziffern) ist π eben keine Nummer, da π irrational (und sogar transzendent) ist und daher durch keine endliche Aneinanderreihung von Ziffern ausgedrückt werden kann. Aber man kann das als Klugscheißen ansehen; *Ich* hätte *diese* Antwort akzeptiert. :)

Comment: @bitmask Guter Einwand. Die Definition, die der Duden für „Zahl“ gibt (habe ich oben in Antwort auf fzwo zitiert) ist besser als meine.

Comment: @bitmask: π ist ja auch keine Nummer - wenn auch eine Zahl.

Comment: Zusammengesetzte Ziffern ergeben Zahlen.

Comment: @MartinPeters Hmm ja. Und?

Answer (score 14):

Aus [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nummer):

> Eine **Nummer** (Abk. Nr., veraltet №, auch #) ist ein meist numerischer, das heißt aus einer Ziffernfolge bestehender Identifikator, der zur Kennzeichnung und Ordnung von Objekten (Kapitel, Ausweise, Häuser, Fußballspieler…) verwendet wird.

Eine Nummer ist *meist* numerisch, aber eben nicht immer. Meine Passnummer beispielsweise beginnt mit einem Buchstaben, gefolgt von Ziffern.

Comment: +1. Für viele ist es schon schwierig, zwischen Ziffern und Zahlen zu unterscheiden. Und jetzt sollen auch Nummern keine Zahlen sein, au wei.

Answer (score 14):

Es ist ganz einfach:

### ZAHL

Etwas, mit dem man rechnen kann (im mathematischen Sinn). Also etwas bei dem es sinnvoll sein kann, es in einer Addition oder einer anderen mathematischen Operation mit einer anderen Zahl zu verknüpfen.

Beispiele für Zahlen:

> **3** Die Menge der Eier in meinem Kühlschrank. Wenn ich eines davon aufesse, bleiben noch zwei über: 3 − 1 = 2
>   **29,7** Die Länge eines DIN-A4-Blattes, gemessen in Zentimeter. Wenn ich das mit der Breite des Blattes multipliziere, erhalte ich dessen Fläche.
>   **8.400.000** Das Jahresgehalt des Daimler-Chefs Dieter Zetsche (in Euro). Von dieser Zahl kann man schon einige Ausgaben abziehen, bis das Resultat negativ wird.

### ZIFFER

Eine Ziffer verhält sich zu einer Zahl wie ein Buchstabe zu einem Wort.
Ziffern sind also die Zeichen, mit denen man Zahlen schreibt. Im alltäglichen Dezimalsystem gibt es genau zehn Ziffern, nämlich 0, 1, 2 usw. bis 9. Die Mathematik kennt aber unendlich viele Zahlensysteme. Das kleinste ist das Binärsystem, das nur zwei Ziffern kennt (0 und 1). Gebräuchlich sind auch das Oktalsystem (Ziffern von 0 bis 7) und das Hexadezimalsystem, das 16 Ziffern hat. Im Fall des Hexadezimalsystems müssen zu den zehn »normalen« Ziffern sechs weitere hinzugenommen werden, um ein Set von 16 verschiedenen Ziffern zu erhalten. Das sind üblicherweise die Kleinbuchstaben a bis f oder die Großbuchstaben A bis F.

Beispiele für Ziffern:

> **3** Die erste Ziffer der Zahl π (3,14159265…)
>   **5** Die Ziffer, mit der die aktuelle Jahreszahl (2015) endet.
>   **d** Jene Ziffer des Hexadezimalsystems, deren Wert der Zahl 13 entspricht.

Das Wort »Ziffer« wird manchmal (streng genommen aber fälschlicherweise) auch als Synonym für »Zahl« verwendet:

> Die Dunkel*ziffer* liegt deutlich höher.
>   In den Industrienationen sinkt die Geburten*ziffer* seit Jahrzehnten immer weiter ab.

### NUMMER

Eine Nummer ist ein systematischer Name. Mit einer Nummer will man nicht rechnen, weil es sinnlos ist, mit Namen Arithmetik zu betreiben. Und weil viele Nummern aus mehr als aus einem Zeichen bestehen, sind es auch keine Ziffern.

Ein systematischer Name ist ein Name, der nicht nach Belieben vergeben wird, sondern nach einem strengen Schema. Postleitzahlen sind gute Beispiele dafür, obwohl sie eigentlich *Postleitnummern* heißen müssten. Sie haben mehr als eine Stelle, und niemand kommt ernsthaft auf die Idee, die Postleitzahlen zweier Gemeinden zu addieren. Diese Nummern wurden von der Post nach einem wohl durchdachten Schema vergeben und sind nichts weiter als Namen für Zustellgebiete.

Beispiele für Nummern:

> **6a** Die Hausnummer in der Adresse meiner Schwester
>   **WDD2048618M15379X** Eine Fahrgestellnummer
>   **360850401X** Eine ISBN (internationale Standard-Buch-Nummer)
>   **10.10.2** Die aktuelle Versionsnummer meines Betriebssystems

---

### Aufzählungen

Nachdem man mit den Benennungen von Aufzählungen nicht rechnen will, und weil sie gelegentlich auch mehrstellig werden können und daher als Ziffern nicht durchgehen, gehören sie zur Gruppe der Nummern. Das sollte auch deswegen klar sein, weil es sich dabei um systematische Namen handelt. Wenn man in Österreich über die Abschaffung des Paragraphen 188 im StGB diskutiert, verwendet man »188« wie einen Namen. Und weil diese Paragraphen-Namen nach einem bestimmten System vergeben werden, sind das systematische Namen, also Nummern.

Und weil sich für Aufzählungen nicht nur Ziffern-Kombinationen eignen, sondern auch Buchstaben-Kombinationen (denke an die Spaltennamen eines Tabellenkalkulationsprogramms), sind auch Buchstaben, wenn sie als Namen für Punkte in Aufzählungen dienen, Nummern.

Comment: Ich will schon mit Nummern rechnen. Der Song sprang in den Top Ten von 5 auf 2, also um 2 Plätze vor. In den letzten 7 Wochen war der Hit im Schnitt auf Platz 7. Dass man gelegentlich nicht rechnen will beweist nicht, dass man nie rechnen will.

Comment: @userunknown 2, 5 und 7 sind in dem Beispiel aber keine Nummern (im Sinne von Huberts Definition), sondern Zahlen - Ordinalzahlen, um genau zu sein. Man könnte darüber streiten, ob *Nummer* gelegentlich "falsch" im Sinne von *Zahl* benutzt wird (analog zu Ziffer/Zahl); das Vergeben von Ordinalzahlen wird ja als *nummerieren* bezeichnet (und das Angeben einer Größe oder Anzahl als *beziffern*).

Comment: @Matthias: Nein. Die Position auf der Liste etwas, was die Zahl die auch eine Nummer ist, misst, selbst wenn es nur eine Ordinalskala ist und in der einen Woche ein Platz 7 mehr verkaufte CDs bedeuten kann als in einer anderen Woche Platz 2. In der einen Woche hatten 6 andere Werke mehr Käufer und in der anderen nur eins - ein klarer Beweis dass man mit den Zahlen rechnen kann und es also Zahlen sind.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich fasse zusammen: Du behauptest in deinem ersten Kommentar implizit (aber fälschlicherweise, und ohne es zu begründen), die Zahlen, mit denen die Einträge in einer Rangliste versehen sind, wären Nummern, und stellst dann ganz richtig fest, dass man damit rechnen kann. Daraus leitest du ab, es gäbe auch Nummern mit denen man rechnen könne. Als die Matthias darauf hinweist, das es sich hierbei um Ordinalzahlen handelt, antwortest du mit einem Satz den ich wegen der darin enthaltenen Grammatikfehler leider nicht ganz verstehe. (Fortsetzung im nächsten Kommentar) ...

Comment: ... (Fortsetzung): Aber dann schreibst du ganz richtig, dass man mit diesen **Zahlen** (!) rechnen kann, und es also Zahlen sind. Das kann ich nur aus vollem Herzen bestätigen. Wenn du damit aber - wie ich vermute - deine erste Aussage, es gäbe **Nummern** mit denen man rechnen will/kann, bekräftigen wolltest, hast du es auf eine etwas unverständliche Weise getan.

Comment: Ja, @HubertSchölnast, es ist ein 'ist' zu wenig und wahrscheinlich mehrere Kommas. "Die Position auf der Liste ist etwa, was die Zahl, die auch eine Nummer ist, misst ...'. Ich finde die Aussage "mit einer Nummer will man nicht rechnen" geht zu weit. Anhand der Beispiele: Wenn ich vor der Hausnummer 6a stehe weiß ich, in welche Richtung Hausnummer 8 zu suchen ist und kann eine grobe Schätzung der Entfernung vornehmen. Bei Version 10.10.2 kann ich angeben, dass es bis 10.10.5 3 Updates gegeben hat. Umgekehrt ist die Aussage eine Zahl sei etwas, womit man rechnen kann, zu weit. Bsp.:af+ag=a(f+g)

Comment: @userunknown: Rechnen ist addieren, multiplizieren usw. Wie sieht die Rechnung aus, mit der du aus »6a« *berechnest* in welche Richtung du gehen musst, um zum Haus mit der Nummer 8 zu gelangen? Bei 10.10.2 kannst du *nicht* mit wissen, wie die Version nach dem dritten Update heißen wird. Das könnte auch 10.10.3.1 sein, oder vielleicht auch 11.0. Und in »af+ag=a(f+g)« kommen gar keine Zahlen vor, sondern Variable (das sind Platzhalter die anstelle von Zahlen in einer Formel stehen).

Comment: Richtig, @HubertSchölnast, es kommen gar keine Zahlen vor bei a(f+g), das war meine Behauptung. 
"ZAHL: Etwas, mit dem man rechnen kann (im mathematischen Sinn)." war die Aussage, die als Definition zu weit gefasst wäre. # Bei 10.10.5 kann ich sagen, dass es 3 Versionsschritte der dritten Kategorie sind, die dazwischen liegen. Die umgekehrte Behauptung habe ich nicht getroffen - das ist ein Strohmann. # Die Hausnummer 6a ist kleiner als 8, also muss ich Stadtauswärts gehen um mich der 8 zu nähern.

Comment: @userunknown: Menno! Worauf reitest du herum wenn du mal kein I-Tüpfelchen findest? Wo habe ich denn geschrieben, dass man ausschließlich mit Zahlen rechnen kann? Wenn ich in einem Beitrag über Blechquader schreibe »ein Auto ist etwas mit dem man fahren kann, und eine Mülltonne ist etwas worin man Abfall sammelt«, dann schießt das ja nicht aus, dass man auch mit anderen Dingen fahren kann (Fahrräder). Natürlich kann man mit Variablen rechnen und mit Vektoren und Matrizen und vielen anderen Dingen. Man kann sogar Ziffern als Zahlen interpretieren und damit rechnen. Aber eben nicht mit Nummern!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Tut mir leid wenn es Dich nervt. Die Frage ist, was der Unterschied zw. Buchstabe und Nummer ist und Du beginnst mit einer Zahl, die etwas sein soll, mit dem man rechnen kann. Darauf überlege ich, ob das nun auf Buchstaben und Nummern, die mir so einfallen, zutrifft und siehe, für Buchstaben, alias Variablen, trifft es zu. Ganz so einfach ist es also vielleicht nicht, außer man macht es sich einfach.

Comment: "Mit einer Nummer will man nicht rechnen, weil es sinnlos ist, mit Namen Mathematik zu betreiben." --- ähemm, ich ahne, was du meinst. Nur ist Mathemathik so viel mehr als nur Arithmetik. Zum Beispiel bilden Zeichenfolgen (mit denen u.a. Nummern dargestellt werden) sog. Monoide, und mit denen kann man wunderbar "Mathematik betreiben".

Comment: @Ingo: Ein Monoid ist eine Menge, über der eine innere zweistellige Verknüpfung definiert ist, und die bezüglich dieser Verknüpfung ein neutrales Element enthält. Zeichenfolgen erfüllen zwar das Kriterium eine Menge zu sein, aber um daraus ein Monoid oder irgend eine andere algebraische Struktur zu machen, musst du dieser Menge noch eine innere Verknüpfung hinzufügen. Das ist i.A. zwar leicht möglich, muss aber dennoch erst einmal gemacht werden. Zeichenketten (und damit Nummern) sind damit einfach nur simple Mengen, so wie auch Bleistifte, Liebesbeziehungen und Sonnensysteme.

Comment: Ja, Hubert, ganz recht. Es wird halt ständig gemacht. Praktisch jedes Computerprogramm tut es. Ja, man kann sagen, daß heutzutage in Computern mehr mit Zeichenketten (und da besonders mit Nummern! man denke an Datenbankabfragen, Überprüfung von Passwörtern, u.dgl. mehr) herumhantiert wird, als mit Zahlen. Insofern stimmt es schlicht nicht, wenn du schreibst "es ist sinnlos, mit Nummern Mathematik zu betreiben." (Hättest du *Arithmetik* geschrieben, wäre alles gut gewesen.)

Comment: @Ingo: Irgendwie hast du Recht. Ich habe daher das Wort *Mathematik* durch *Arithmetik* ersetzt.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Nummer ist heutzutage nichts anderes als eine willkürliche, aber eindeutige Zeichenfolge. Siehe z. B. das, was auf deinem Nummernschild steht, Nummern von Banknoten usw.

Man kann, muß aber nicht, natürliche Zahlen (bzw. Zeichenfolgen, die auch natürliche Zahlen darstellen) zum Numerieren verwenden. Aus praktischen Gründen möchte man jedoch oft, daß alle Nummern gleich lang sind.

Ein völliger Blödsinn aus mathematischer Sicht ist das Wort "Postleitzahl", denn hier handelt es sich eben nicht um Zahlen, sondern Nummern.

Answer (score 1):

Ich würde hier von **Punkt** a, **Zeile** a, **Abschnitt** a oder **Item** a sprechen.

Nicht hingegen von **Nummer**.

Zeile allerdings nur, wenn der Abschnitt einzeilig ist.

**Edit:**

Im IT-Umfeld können allerdings die Buchstaben A, B, C, D, E, F Ziffern sein und in Hexadezimalzahlen auftreten.

Comment: Eigentlich würde "Ding a" auch wunderbar in die Liste passen. Ich finde, das Wort wird viel zu selten benutzt. Ich war sehr positiv überrascht, als ich die Neuauflage vom Brettspiel Kings & Things öffnete und sich darin tatsächlich ein "Dingebeutel" befand, in den "Dinge" (nahezu alle Plättchen, die es im Spiel gibt) hineinkommen... :)

Comment: @ApoY2k Wieso denn englische Betonung? Das ist Latein, und es war bis vor einiger Zeit unter Gelehrten nicht *sooo* unüblich, Gegenstände per „item“ (['iːtɛm]) aufzuzählen. [[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/item)]

Comment: @Konrad: Hmm, ich hab noch nie ['iːtɛm] gehört. Wann war "vor einiger Zeit"?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Keine Ahnung. Ich würde mal behaupten, in einigen Personenkreisen ist das immer noch üblich. Allerdings eben Altphilologen.

Comment: dict.leo bietet logischerweise als Übersetzung für `item` auch `laufende Nummer` an. q.e.d.

Answer (score 1):

Zeichen als Nummern sind normalerweise nicht gängig, aber da wir Buchstaben häufig intuitiv ihrem Platz (ihrer *Nummer*) im Alphabet zuordnen, kann es passieren, dass man
`a), b), c)`
als gleichbedeutend mit
`1), 2), 3)`
verwendet, da sie von ihrem Einsatzzweck her in diesem Kontext gleichbedeutend sind.

Die Formulierung *"Nummer a"* dürfte aber strenggenommen nicht korrekt sein, ich vermute dahinter also eher die oben beschriebene Assoziation von Buchstaben und ihren, durch das Alphabet zugeordneten, Zahlen.

Comment: Leider auch nicht pedantisch genug gewesen. Als ob '1', '2', '3' keine Zeichen wären! Es sind auch nicht einfach bloß Buchstaben, die Nummern sind - siehe meinen Kommentar zu Konrads Post: Wenn man nach y, z, mit aa, ab, ac weitermacht sieht man, dass es Buchstabenketten oder besser Zeichenketten sind, die Nummern sein können. 17 ist ja auch eine Nummer, und nicht zwei.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever hear of **Beweisstück A, Beweisstück B?** That doesn’t imply a sequential ordering, only Beweisstücke of different kind. That’s imo pretty important point that other answers here miss.

I would agree as stated above, that you **can understand** and use letters as numbers. But I’m highly **missing the sequential character** here. We are used to learn the ABC in a distinct order, but this order is product of a historical convention, but **numbers have a inherent ordering by definition, not convention**

If you compare some **table of contents** of novels, dissertation, manuals, it’s not non-relevant if you use letters or numbers. **Numbers imply that the reader should start with chapter 1**, if a manual is written like a tutorial to teach somebody something, you should use numbers, if it is more a reference book, it makes more sense to use letters (but then the number of letters is limited, so that’s the obvious problem with this system and why numbers are used in very big encyclopedia).

In a **technical dissertation** you will see numbers used for chapters and sections in the table of contents but letters in the **appendix**. Here you see imo pretty well what the purpose of using numbers vs. letters is. It is outside of the ordering and coherent sequential content of the numbered chapters in the dissertation.

Actually wonders me that there doesn’t seem to be a clear convention, but there are good reasons to use letter/number/no mark at all as explained above. I just took a quick look at different encyclopedia, novels, reference books, manual, dissertation pdfs. There is no stringent convention/pattern besides the use of numbered chapters in technical dissertations and letters for the appendix. But you see numbers are often used for chapters, letters for sections/subsections to imply, there is no strict ordering for the reader. **For example, the content of a subsection C doesn’t need the knowledge of subsection B.** It’s common to use letters **and** numbers in tables of contents. So this should be a clear proof.

**So don’t think its fine and doesn’t make any difference to use letters instead of numbers**

Comment: Beweisstück A, B, C mag keine Reihenfolge ausdrücken, ausser der willkürlich festgelegten, die sich aus eben den Nummern ergibt, aber die Reihenfolge wird eben dann wichtig, wenn man in einem Index nach einem Beweisstück sucht.

Answer (score 0):

Diese Buchstaben sind *keine* Nummern.

Aber sie *stellen* Nummern *dar*. So wie in der Algebra.

Comment: Wenn Du mit Algebra `Variablen` meinst, dann ist es falsch, denn a, b, c bedeuten hier eine Reihenfolge, was für Variablen nicht zutrifft. Wenn nein - was ist sonst gemeint mit Algebra? Dass 1, 2, 3 in der Algebra Nummern sind?

Answer (score 0):

Nach meiner Kenntnis sind das mathematisch gesehen Variablen und nicht Nummern.
Ich kann mich auch nicht daran erinnern, dass in meiner Gegenwart eine einigermaßen deutschkundige Person "Nummer a" gesagt hätte.

Comment: Ich möchte widersprechen. Variablen sind variabel. Hier geht es aber nicht um allgemeine variable Platzhalter sondern um etwas konkretes, nämlich den Punkt *a* auf einer Liste. Mathematisch vergleichbar mit *e*, das auch keine Variable sondern eine Konstante ist.